# Android delivers intent to stopped service

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a service that dispatches some `Completable` according to the `intent` in `onStartCommand`, and calls `stopSelf` if all started `Completable`s finished.

I also `dispose` all non-completed ones in `onDestroy` to cleanup everything.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public abstract class RxIntentService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "RxIntentService";

    private SparseArray<Disposable> pendingCommands;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        pendingCommands = new SparseArray<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + startId);
        Completable completable = handleIntent(intent);
        if (completable == null) {
            commandCompleted(startId);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        } else {
            pendingCommands.append(startId,
                    completable
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(
                                    () -> commandCompleted(startId),
                                    throwable -> {
                                        Log.w(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + " command failed: " + (intent == null ? "intent is null" : intent.getAction()), throwable);
                                        commandCompleted(startId);
                                    })
            );
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }
    }

    private void commandCompleted(int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "commandCompleted: " + getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + startId);
        pendingCommands.remove(startId);
        if (pendingCommands.size() == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "commandCompleted: will stop self");
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        for (int i = 0; i < pendingCommands.size(); i++) {
            pendingCommands.valueAt(i).dispose();
        }
        pendingCommands.clear();
        pendingCommands = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected abstract Completable handleIntent(Intent intent);
}
```

The code seems to be quite-safe and clean. Conceptually it works like an `IntentService`, but in `RxJava` way so that it is not single-threaded.

However, I observed a weird behaviour: Just after calling `stopSelf` and before `onDestroy`, android delivers another intent to this to-be-stopped service. It dispatches another `Completable` as expected but since `onDestroy` is called because of `stopSelf`, the most recent `Completable` is disposed before completion.

I have `ProfileService` that extends `RxIntentService` with the following logs:

```
D/RxIntentService: onStartCommand: ProfileService, 1
D/RxIntentService: onStartCommand: ProfileService, 2
D/RxIntentService: commandCompleted: ProfileService, 1
D/RxIntentService: commandCompleted: ProfileService, 2
D/RxIntentService: commandCompleted: will stop self
D/RxIntentService: onStartCommand: ProfileService, 3
D/RxIntentService: onDestroy: ProfileService
```

How can I prevent this behaviour? I can check in `onStartCommand` whether it is about to be destroyed, but then how can I handle this particular intent?

Comment: What is the use-case for this class? Your question hints that it's used like an `IntentService`, but an `IntentService` is for doing some short work off the UI thread, and that makes me wonder where/why you'd want to use this over just using Rx at the call site.

Comment: @PPartisan The use case is, user chooses profile picture and I sync it in the background. Why not handle it in activity/fragment? The user may press home just after choosing the picture, and it will be disposed on `onStop`. Also due to poor network connection, it may take more than a few seconds. So I thought it would be better to use a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I need to use `stopSelfResult(startId)` instead of `stopSelf()`, as stated [here](http://file:///Users/john/Library/Android/sdk/docs/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelfResult(int)):

> Stop the service if the most recent time it was started was startId. This is the same as calling stopService(Intent) for this particular service but allows you to safely avoid stopping if there is a start request from a client that you haven't yet seen in onStart(Intent, int).

It directly addresses my problem about the intents that haven't been observed in `onStartCommand`.